# Where does Shadowmere respawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the last quest for the blades, and I had to go talk to Paratharax at the throat of the world. I decided not to kill Paratharax until I finished the all the Greybeards quests.

I decided to take a shortcut down the side of the mountain, riding Shadowmere, and we fell. Shadowmere died. I fast travelled to Whiterun, waited 10 days, and went back to where he died, but he still wasn't there.

I went back to doing quests. I know its been at least 100 days since he died, and I saw on here that you have to wait 15-20 days, so I'm wondering if it has been too long.

If he did, where would he respawn? On the top of the Throat of the world, down the side of the mountain where he died, or at the position he came to rest?

Answer (score 0):

He should respawn in 20-25 in-game days at the place of death.

It's a pain, I know, but that horse makes dragon fights easy!